# Calling Child click event when parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I am having a third party plugin that is adding a button on the click of this button a specific function is done.

Now I am wrapping this `button` into a `div`. Now I want that when I click on this wrapper `div` then it should click the `button` that is inside it.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

banner.click(function() {
  console.log('Parent is calling child');
  button.trigger('click');

  // What shall I place here to stop parent calling itself
})

// This is 3rd party service that is handling this.
button.on("click", function() {
  console.log('I am called here');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/8a33n7qg/

Problem : On `div` click => button click is done => button click is again propagated to parent => then again button click and so on.

So I want to stop this after first time, I can't change the third party plugin and I am avoiding global solutions. Is there any easy solution ?

**Note : I CAN'T CHANGE THE BUTTON CODE, SINCE IT COMING FROM THIRD PARTY PLUGIN**

Thank You for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your need to place a call to `stopPropagation()` in the event raised from the child button, *not* the parent `div` as your comments suggest:

```js
var $banner = $("#banner-message");
var $button = $("button");

$banner.click(function(){
  console.log('Parent is calling child');
  $button.trigger('click');
})

$button.on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('I am called here');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

> I can't change the third party plugin, I have tried to show a demo with small code, the button click is handled in third part plugin.

In this case you can use the `target` property of the click event on the `div` to check if the button was the triggering element, and do nothing if so:

```js
var $banner = $("#banner-message");
var $button = $("button");

$banner.click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('button')) 
    return false; 
    
  console.log('Parent is calling child');    
  $button.trigger('click');
})

$button.on("click", function() {
  console.log('I am called here');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't change the third party plugin, I have tried to show a demo with small code, the button click is handled in third part plugin.

Comment: Yes that helped, Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Just use `event.stopPropagation()` in button on handler to stop propagating the event.

Comment: It is coming form third party plugin and , I can't change the third party plugin